# Creating readable html with django templates

Tags: python, html, django, templates

When using Django for html templating how do I create good html markup formatting.

I am trying to make use of content blocks.  But the content blocks show up at different levels of indentation in different templates.  How do I get the content blocks to show indented like it would be if someone was to hand write the html.

I am having the same problem with newlines; I can smash all the blocks together in the template. At that point the html looks better, but the templates are unmaintainable.

I guess the question is how to you create pretty html markup with the django templating system?

I am surprised by the answers so far. I find that nicely formatted HTML aids in writing the corresponding CSS and JavaScript. As well as making it easier to add content later on.

Comment: Why does the HTML layout matter?

Comment: I'd rather do the exact opposite, squash the HTML as tightly as possible so it has as little characters as possible.

Comment: @rebus: Agreed -- smaller downloads faster.  It seems like time spent fussing with HTML is time wasted.  First, it's time wasted in development.  Second, it's time wasted transferring whitespace.  Third, it's time wasted in maintenance trying to preserve all the precious (and meaningless) whitespace.

Comment: Surely nicely readable HTML source isn't worth anything for any average user, but for the average developer it seems like a perfectly legitimate need to have any source in a readable format – especially since this could be taken care of automatically.

Comment: I like to show my html well formatted and I think I'm not the only one.

Comment: @S.Lott HTML layout matters because front-end developers need to look at the raw source (not what is actually parsed and viewable in web inspectors) from time to time to help diagnose cross-browser issues.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Christian S. Perone from Pyevolve has [exactly what you're looking for](http://blog.christianperone.com/?p=814). He uses middleware to intercept the HTTPResponse object and run it through [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

I'd imagine that your site will suffer a slight performance hit, though. I recommend running some benchmarks before deploying this middleware to a production site.

Answer (score 4):

You can override the NodeList's render method as I've done. See my question with working code:

[Proper indentation in Django templates (without monkey-patching)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308626/how-to-modify-django-template-system-without-monkey-patching-to-achieve-proper)

Answer (score 0):

I'm impressed you care about the resulting html - I only worry about getting the templates tidy and readable!  But in answer to your question, have you looked at middleware?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

Then use the Tidy python module to reformat the html.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PythonTidy/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to run the output of the template engine through an HTML tidier, such as [µTidylib](http://utidylib.berlios.de/).

Answer (score 0):

The readability of HTML doesn't matter.  In a system like Django or Rails, HTML is an output format, not a source format.  When people edit HTML by hand, they are right to be concerned about indentation and spacing, because it is a source format, and someone will have to edit it in the future.  But the output of templates is just that: output.  The browser doesn't care about the indentation.  At this point the only people who read the HTML are people looking at View - Source.

Comment: And the only person doing that is probably the OP's project manager, who is now willing to invest a few thousand dollars to please his eyes ;-) +1

Comment: This assumes that you never look at the output to try and debug the templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Django Templates to do string-formatting of long-but-simple strings, you can use Python's triple-quoted strings with .format() in a function def:

```
def templated_string(context_dict):
    return '''This is an example
of a long string across multiple lines.
It can be used to format {something} for 
{name}'s own purposes, even though
it looks funny in code'''.format(**context_dict)
```

Then `templated_string({'name': 'rileymat', 'something': 'whatever you want'})` does the sensible thing. You can generate raw HTML that way... which then has exactly the whitespace you ask for.